# "This is a debugging block" on Permissions page

Tags: debugging, users

On my dev site, everything is working fine EXCEPT the permissions pages.  This includes `/admin/people/permissions` and the permissions pages for individual modules (example: `/admin/people/permissions#module-advanced_forum`).

I have the [Faster Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/fp) module installed, and this module gives a list of all the modules installed with links directly to their individual permissions. This page is working fine.

All of these pages are working fine in my production site, so there is something about my dev site that is causing this error. Has this happened to anyone before? What could be the problem?

[image: screenshot]

FYI, debugging blocks have been turned off in settings.

Comment: Your screenshot is a dead link and your question is very hard to understand. Please rephrase. What is "Faster Permissions page"?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Omega theme debugging blocks are always visible to uid=1. Check out this [issue](http://drupal.org/node/1408516).

Comment: Thanks Triskelion for your advice, however the login I'm using is user 3586. I am using Omega, however. Considering this issue doesn't happen in my production site, could there be something wrong with my settings in my test site? Could time out settings have anything to do with this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have figured it out. My site seems to have a lot more permissions set than other Drupal sites.  I just doubled the PHP memory limit to 1 GB and the page loaded ALMOST normally. I got an unresponsive script warning. I then looked at the error log for the site and saw that the PHP was timing out, so I doubled the timeout. Now the permissions page loads as it should.